# Using Dispatch, Async Programming to make Code Block Wait

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have 2 functions (func A() and func B()). I want to know how to make function B wait for function A to execute before proceeding. I've done a lot of reading, and know we can somehow do it with asynchronous programming and semaphores, or with functions such as dispatch_barrier_sync. However, I'm really new to swift, and am not understanding how to code this. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
A()
B()

}
```

Comment: What are you doing in function a can you share it?

Comment: In function A and B both, I'm making queries to my Parse database

Comment: Parse has methods that include callbacks for when the operation has completed. You're better off calling your functions from there.

Comment: Could you direct me to those methods and how to use them for this scenario? I couldn't find them in the parse documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func a(completion: ()->Void){
  let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
  query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZ4YEGZ", block: { (object, error) -> Void in
    if let object = object{
      completion()
    }
  })
}

func b(){
  //get your other object
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  a(){ () -> Void in
    //Call B when A is completed
    b()
  }
}
```

Here we add a completion block to function A.
We call this block when the object has been returned.
When we call function A we use the `{ () -> Void in ……}` to execute code only when function A has been completed.

(Code after [abhishekkarwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1356068/abhishekkharwar))

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where do I add in the rest of my code for the query in function A? I'm takling about:
                if error == nil { for object in objects {

Comment: also I'm using findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock so would my code just look like : findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(block: { (object, error) -> Void in
    if let object = object{
      completion()
    }
  })

Answer (score 0):

// Please convert bellow code in swift

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 [self functionAWithCompletion:^(){
    //After completion of a cal b function
   [self functionB];
}];

}

- (void)functionAWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

     completion();
}];

}

- (void)functionb{


}
```